# Extract the first x observations in each column while keeping the indexing by row in R

Tags: r

The following code is designed to extract the first x observations of each column, which are time series spanning different periods. (or to erase everything else than the x first values in each column …)
The first values, can be numbers followed by `NAs`, as long as it is the beginning of the time series.
This is crucial that each value stay linked to its own place in the indexing (the first column 'Year')

```
# data example
df <- data.frame("Year" = 1791:1800,
                  "F1" = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.2,1.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  "F2" = c(NA, NA, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, NA, NA, NA),
                  "F3" = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                  "F4" = c(NA, 3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9))
```

```
# Convert the dataframe to a list by column
long <- setNames(lapply(names(df)[-1], function(x) cbind(df[1], df[x])), names(df)[-1])
# and select only the first 3 elements after NAs in each column
mylist <- lapply(long, function(x){
  head(na.omit(x), 3)
})
```

```
# or in a more concise writing ??
mylist2 <- lapply(df, function(x){
    head(na.omit(cbind(df[[1]],x)), 3)
  })
```

```
# Now ‘mylist’  (or ‘mylist2’) contains several vector of different lengths, 
# not very appropriate for dataframe, let's switch to long format dataframe
mydata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(x){
  require(reshape2)
  melt(x, id.vars="Year")
})
)
# and switch back to regular spreadsheet format
library(tidyverse)
mydataCOL <- spread(mydata, key = "variable", value = "value")
write.table(mydataCOL, “sheet1.txt”)
```

This thing is complicated to apply to a list of dataframe (multiple excel files). Is there an easier way to achieve this ? To do such operations on each column of each dataframe of the list :)

I'm currently trying with 'nested' `lapply()` :

```
mylist <- lapply(d, function(x){
  lapply(x, function(y){
    head(na.omit(cbind(x[[1]],y)), 50)
  })
})
```

but this is not the easiest way I guess... Thanks !

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to retrieve max `x` _non-NA_ observations from your dataframe columns.

Suppose `x` is 5. In the code, it is denoted by `n_obs` which you can change.

```n_obs = 5
    apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) {
      first_x_obs = data.frame(df[1],x) %>% 
        filter(!is.na(x))
      if (nrow(first_x_obs)>=n_obs){
        first_x_obs[1:n_obs,]
      }else {
        first_x_obs
      }
    }
    ) ```
Let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the tidyverse anyway, why not go all in with Hadley's stuff?

```
GetTop <- function(indf){
  indf %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Year,names_to="F") %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(F) %>%
    top_n(3,wt=-Year) %>%                                                                                                      
    pivot_wider(names_from="F")
}
```

Now if we can call it for one dataframe

```
> mytops <- GetTop(df)
```

If you have a list of these dataframes you can use lapply to do this to each one.

```
allmytop <- lapply(biglist,FUN=GetTop)
```

That will give you a list of dataframes. Seems like you also want to join them into one fat dataframe.

```
fatdf <- lapply(biglist,FUN=GetTop) %>% reduce(full_join,by="Year")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this. How do you got such functions `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` in the tidyverse ??

Comment: They are new. If you don't have them you need to do update.packages(). https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/pivot.html